# Is there any reason as to why, in Leibniz notation, the independent variable of a derivative is written the way it is?

Tags: derivatives, notation

The n-th derivative of $y(t)$ in leibniz notation is simply:

$$y^{(n)}=\frac{\mathrm{d}^ny}{\mathrm{d}t^n}$$

Obviously, this is just notation and it's not necessarily meant to be as logical or as consistent as possible. However, why is written in that way and not in the, I assume more logical:

$$y^{(n)}=\frac{\mathrm{d}^ny}{\mathrm{d}^nt}$$

After all, the first notation can be confusing if, for example, you have a second derivative with respect to $t^2$. So is it simply tradition? If so, is there any original reason as to why it was written this way?

Comment: False chain rule: $\dfrac{d^ny}{dt^n} \cdot \dfrac{dt^n}{dt} = \dfrac{d^ny}{dt^n} \cdot nt^{n-1} = \dfrac{d^ny}{dt}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "logic" (such as it is) for the notation is like this:
The derivative is $\frac{dy}{dx}$, or written as an "operator",
$$
y' = \frac{d}{dx}\;y .
$$
So for higher derivatives, say the third derivative,
$$
y''' = \frac{d}{dx}\;\frac{d}{dx}\;\frac{d}{dx}\;y .
$$
Thinking of the usual rules for multiplication and fractions, this is
$$
y''' = \frac{dddy}{dx\;dx\;dx} = 
\frac{d^3\;y}{dx^3}
$$
Of course we need to realize that $dx^3$ means $(dx)^3$ and not $d(x^3)$.

Answer (score 3):

It is basically the derivative operation  respective to $t$ applied $n$ times to the dependent $y$.

$$\left(\dfrac{\mathrm d~~}{\mathrm d t}\right)^n y$$